# Cannot view images in web application form after adding authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I'm trying to build a website which based on ASP.net. I made the main function first, I need to make the website secure. So I set the web.config like:

```
<system.web>
      <authorization>
          <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
      <authentication mode="Forms">
          <forms loginUrl="~/Register/Login.aspx" timeout="2800"/>
      </authentication>

      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>
```

When I delete those code, I can add any image or any elements, and they will shows. But if I add those code, the images will not shows. Is there anyone have any idea about it?

Answer (score 0):

In your web.config, after `</system.web>` add code like this:

```
<location path="images">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

And repeat for every other required data, like css, javascript, etc.

Comment: Is that means once I change this configuration, I can add anything I want, and after all, I can change it back?

Answer (score 0):

You want `<allow users="*"/>` for public pages (including images) instead of `<deny users="?" />`

`deny user="?"` means denies access to the anonymous user.

[ASP.NET Membership – Handling Authenticated Users that are Not Authorized.](http://www.misfitgeek.com/asp-net-membership-handling-authenticated-users-that-are-not-authorized/)